# What is the alternative of append data bound items for DropdownList in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.list,
      new { @style = "width:100%", @class = "form-control" })
```

This can help to set the selected item only at run time.
How to add few more items at run time (inside controller )

Comment: change the contents of "list" before you return from the controller action?? Presumably you have control of this?

Comment: Thanks Adyson , I will try that

Comment: Can we also define a SelectList in model with some few default items ?

Comment: I would make "list" a list of SelectListItem , add the default values and then merge your DB data into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple change the source before assigning it to your ViewBag.

e.g:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> yourSource = //...;
var list = yourSource.ToList();
list.Add(...);
ViewBag.list = list;
```